# What is the UI framework used by the Amazon Cloud player

Tags: user-interface, audio-player

How can I find out what UI framework the Amazon Cloud Player is using.
At least for the PC, is it just a shell that is running HTML5/JavaScript ? If so is it using a standard UI framework? The fluidity and responsiveness of the UI seems remarkable to me, compared to any other PC based, iTunes like, music players.

Comment: It might be custom.  You could always inspect the sources that it pulls across (and I wouldn't be surprised to at least see jQuery in that bundle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon Cloud Player uses a lot of Open Source components.
Just open the player and open Help > About Amazon music > Legal notice

In my case the following link was opened 
http://www.amazon.de/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201415470&pop-up=1
The page gives a good overview of what is used.

Among the components are jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap. Probably Twitter bootstrap is the UI framework you are looking for.